# ¿ Por qué no retorna el arreglo a la función principal?

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++

estoy intentado que el arreglo que se rellena en la funcion prueba me retorne a la funcion main para poder mostrarlo por pantalla en la funcion main pero cuando lo compilo solo me aparece la linea anterior  $:
y no me muestra el contenido del arreglo

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


int prueba(int n[10]){
    
    
    
    for(int i=0;i==10;i++){
        
      n[i]=i;
        
    }
    for(int i=0;i==10;i++){
        
     return n[i];
        
    }


}
int main(){
    
 int arr[10];
 int arr2[10];
 arr2[10]=prueba(arr);
 
 cout<<"$:";
    for(int i=0;i==10;i++){
        
     arr2[i];
        
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay errores de dos tipos: de sintaxis y de semántica
**De sintaxis:**
 La estructura del bloque for está mal planteada.
**De semántica:**
 Un arreglo es un puntero, tira error si se establecen subíndices cuando se declara como  parámetros de un subproceso, por lo que un arreglo va sin argumentos. La ventaja es que lo arreglos pasan por referencia. Está mal la lectura de los datos.
 Aquí el código completo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

void prueba(int arr[], int n);

void prueba(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[10];
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout << "Ingrese el dato " << i+1 << ":" << endl;
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    cout << "El arreglo ingresado fue" << endl;
    prueba(arr,10);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: pero en tu respuesta no retorna el arreglo a la funcion principal

Comment: No, lo llamo y escribe el arreglo en el subproceso. No creo que se pueda retornar el arreglo a la función principal, porque si se pasa como parámetro no pasan los elementos.

Comment: y si se usa un puntero y se iguala el puntero a un arreglo

Comment: No sé como sería eso. Llevas los números del arreglo al subproceso para traerlos de nuevo. No le hallo sentido a tu lógica.